# laravel route issue .the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel

I want to show data from the database when I press the button in one view it displays me the specific data by the id in the other view [this is my first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWuwl.png).

In my controller:

```
public function show($id) {
    $symptoms=symptoms::all();
    foreach ($symptoms as $symptom) $symptom=symptoms::find($id);
    return view('front.second',compact('symptom'));
}
```

My problem is when displays the second view it can't find the page and the route  just display the id not the method/id :(

Comment: public function show($id)
    {
        $symptoms=symptoms::all();
        foreach ($symptoms as $symptom)
            $symptom=symptoms::find($id);

        return view('front.second',compact('symptom'));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show(symptoms $symptom)
{
    return view('front.second', compact('symptom'));
}
```

Or:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $symptom = symptoms::find($id);
    return view('front.second', compact('symptom'));
}
```

And read [Laravel's Controllers Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As you shared image, is clearly shows that you are using below route

```
{{route('show',['id'=>111])}}
```

Check your route by `php artisan route:list` and use right one, I guess you should use like

```
{{route('user.show',['id'=>111])}}
```

If you Controller name is `UserController` in resource